# Hiding and Showing dynamically generated table rows with help of a single button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table generated with dynamic data in a WordPress Section with a custom requirement where the  "table rows greater than 3 should be hidden by default. And function which should toggle show more rows or show fewer table rows with one button. But however, I have achieved it with two different functions. I need help in cascading these two functions with a single button.

Like a button below the table which shows "Show More" once clicked all the dynamic table rows will be displayed. And the same button should show "Show less" after it's clicked and hide back to the default state.

I know for the fact the script is very tiresome on the server, any alternatives would be much appreciated!

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" class="tablec">
            <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th><strong>Floor Plan</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Dimension</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
            
           
function RemoveSpecialChar($str)
{
     $res = str_replace( array( '\'', '"',
    ',' , ';', '<', 'West', 'Floor Plan', '>' , '-' ), ' ', $str);
    return $res;
}


            
        foreach( $floor_plans as $plans ) { $i++; 
       
        if($plans['fave_plan_title'] == "Master Plan"){
            break;
        }
        
        ?>
                        <tr id="<?php echo $i;?>" class="<?php echo $i;?>">
         
         <td> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $plans['fave_plan_image'] ); ?>" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
      <img class="borderr" src="<?php echo esc_url( $plans['fave_plan_image'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $plans['fave_plan_description']; ?>" width="100" height="100" title="<?php echo $plans['fave_plan_description']; ?>">
          </a></td>
         
         <td>
             
           <?php 
           
            $str=ltrim(chop($plans['fave_plan_description'],"Floor Plan"), get_the_title());
           
            $str1 = RemoveSpecialChar($str);
            echo $str1;
           
           ?> <br>
           <b><?php echo esc_attr( $plans['fave_plan_size'] ); ?> Sqft</b>
           
           </td>
         
               <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button></td>
            </tr>
            
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table> <br>
                    <div class="wrapperr">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show()">Show All <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size:14px"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hide()">Show Less <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="font-size:14px"></i></button>
                    </div>
        </div><!-- block-content-wrap -->
    </div><!-- block-wrap -->
</div><!-- property-floor-plans-wrap -->
<?php } ?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    
    document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('5').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('6').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('7').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('8').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('9').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('10').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('11').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('12').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('13').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('14').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('15').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('16').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('17').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('18').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('19').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('20').style.display = 'none';


function hide() {

    document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('5').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('6').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('7').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('8').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('9').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('10').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('11').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('12').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('13').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('14').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('15').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('16').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('17').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('18').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('19').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('20').style.display = 'none';
}

  function show() {
  
  var a = document.getElementById("4");
  var b = document.getElementById("5");
  var c = document.getElementById("6");
  var d = document.getElementById("7");
  var e = document.getElementById("8");
  var f = document.getElementById("9");
  var g = document.getElementById("10");
  var h = document.getElementById("11");
  var i = document.getElementById("12");
  var j = document.getElementById("13");
  var k = document.getElementById("14");
  var l = document.getElementById("15");
  var m = document.getElementById("16");
  var n = document.getElementById("17");
  var o = document.getElementById("18");
  var p = document.getElementById("19");
  var q = document.getElementById("20");
    
    a.style.display = "";
    b.style.display = "";
    c.style.display = "";
    d.style.display = "";
    e.style.display = "";
    f.style.display = "";
    g.style.display = "";
    h.style.display = "";
    i.style.display = "";
    j.style.display = "";
    k.style.display = "";
    l.style.display = "";
    m.style.display = "";
    n.style.display = "";
    o.style.display = "";
    p.style.display = "";
    q.style.display = "";
}  
</script>
```

A working example of the same can be seen in the below-mentioned link, look for the floor plan section : https://doorsandshelters.com/property/sowparnika-indraprastha-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from @gaurav arora's answer, a more clean & maintainable approach.

Instead of having 2 buttons and different `onClick` handlers, just use a single button and with a jquery function toggle the rows and the button text. Having 2 buttons would be buggy.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary toggleFloorPlans">Show more <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size:14px"></i></button>
```

JQuery should go at the very bottom of your file:

```
<script>
let shown = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggleFloorPlans").click(function(){
        var thisEl = $(".toggleFloorPlans"); 
        if(shown){
            jQuery("tr:gt(3)").hide()
            thisEl.text('Show more')
            shown = false;
        } else {
            jQuery("tr:gt(3)").show();
            thisEl.text('Show less')
            shown = true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I've used this jquery CDN, replace this with yours and should be good to work.

This should be above the jquery function above.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update:
Show up/down arrow

```
<script>
let shown = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggleFloorPlans").click(function(){
        var thisEl = $(".toggleFloorPlans"); 
        if(shown){
            jQuery("tr:gt(3)").hide()
            thisEl.text(`Show more`)
            thisEl.append('<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size:14px"></i>');
            shown = false;
        } else {
            jQuery("tr:gt(3)").show();
            thisEl.text('Show less');
            thisEl.append('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="font-size:14px"></i>');
            shown = true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: works perfectly! As expected, but how do I incorporate the arrow icon? <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size:14px"></i> and <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="font-size:14px"></i> accordingly?

Comment: the answer worked like a charm! But how do I put across the arrow icons with the button text?

Comment: @user3787062 check updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle it why client-side scripts only.
A better solution may be using jquery greater than selector

```
html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggle(event)">Show More<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="font-size:14px"></i></button> 

javascript

var shown = false;
function toggle(e){
if(shown){
jQuery("tr:gt(3)").hide()
e.target.innerText('Show more')
}else{
jQuery("tr:gt(3)").show()
e.target.innerText('Show less')
}
}
```

Comment: Ok how do I use this concept for one button; where button text changes to Show less after click and remain Show more by default?

Comment: updated my answer with refrence.

Comment: I have src='https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>

Comment: It's not working. Should I change something

Comment: any exceptions?

Comment: No i have it updated live on the link. Please check https://doorsandshelters.com/property/sowparnika-indraprastha-2

Comment: seems Like your JS not getting loaded, It throwing an error it is not able to find the toggle function.

Comment: you need to call 
`jQuery("tr:gt(3)").hide()` as the initialally rows should be hidden.

Comment: So how do I proceed further sir?

Comment: I don't know how you are injecting the JS, maybe creating a js file or adding it manually in index.html.

Comment: So I have called it initially in a separate script tag. now the <tr> grater than 3 is hidden initially. But the button event is not getting triggered!

Comment: adding it manually on the index page. You can view source on the link for the same.

Comment: you need to add a function keyword before the toggle, updated the answer

Comment: Have added it now. But still the event is not getting triggered!

Comment: remove the $ sign from html, inside the toggle argument

Comment: removed the $ sign. Show is working now but hiding isn't and the button text also doesn't change